# PHP array CSS attribute selector

Tags: php, css

Does anyone know the CSS syntax to add an attribute selector that uses PHP array style name attribute for the form element.

I want something like input[name=attrValue[]].dspNone, but the [] is not working in my style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word. Quotes.

```
input[name="attrValue[]"]
```